# DSA module in Python

Tags: python, cryptography

Does anyone know of a pure DSA module in Python for signing messages?

Answer (score 1):

[Python Cryptography Toolkit](http://www.amk.ca/python/code/crypto) has this [module](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/gdata/Crypto/PublicKey/DSA.py)

[Chilkat](http://www.example-code.com/python/dsa.asp) (this may be a pure module check with chilkat - commercially licensed  )

Answer (score 1):

If OpenSSL has the functionality you are looking for, try [pyOpenSSL](https://launchpad.net/pyopenssl).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you might have to use a wrapper to some non-Python implementation, like pyOpenSSL. I'm not aware of any pure Python crypto library that is secure.

In particular, pycrypto is a piece of crap. E.g., if you use DSA as proposed
[here by the author](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/#the-elgamal-and-dsa-algorithms) then the attack described in the paper "*The Insecurity of the Digital Signature Algorithm with partially known nonces*" by Nguyen and Shparlinski can be used to find the secret key very very fast.
Note, that this paper has been presented in 2002, but pycrypto is still susceptible to it.
Python is a really nice an friendly language for prototyping, but when it comes to defending against adversaries, it is a little too friendly.

Comment: I guess you refer to the point where the author suggests to use a prime as K. It is indeed the same flaw that the paper mentions (citing Bleichenbacher) for the AT&T library, but the leakage of a single bit is too little to break DSA according to the paper itself (unless further developments have taken place?). Not quite sufficient to qualify pycrypto as "piece of crap" IMO.