# what python package for rsa algorithm

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, privacy, encryption-asymmetric

looking to do RSA encryption on a short string in python. This is for a piece of user data that I want to store without staff (incl myself) being able to see it. The private key will be on a thumbdrive in my safety deposit box for when we get subpoenaed.

**my question:** is there a 'probably correct' python package for asymmetric-key RSA? Will I be safer to use a C library (if so which one).

Comment: Sounds like you actually want symmetric encryption.

Comment: no, it must be asymmetric. the public key lives on the server and my staff can access it.

Comment: Why are you looking for a "probably correct" solution as opposed to a "correct" one?

Comment: @MAK: I think it might be a nod to the old adage "good crypto is hard" - even systems designed with security in mind can have unexpected weaknesses.

Comment: @MAK do you know any packages that are guaranteed correct?

Comment: @amwinter: The implementation of an algorithm is either correct or not. Whether or not it is sufficient for you is another matter. You have already specified what algorithm you want. It is 'correct' if it follows the RSA algorithm, and produces the output expected. If it were incorrect, why would anyone be using it? Yes, RSA does use probabilistic prime checking/generation. There is an infinitesimally small chance that it may produce insecure keys. But 'correctness', as I understand it, refers to whether the implementation follows the algorithm.AFAIK, PyCrypto's implementation is "correct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption of short strings with RSA can be problematic.  There are certain pieces of data you can encrypt with RSA that reveal details about your private key.  In your case it will probably be fine since it will be obscure enough your staff won't figure it out.  But in the general case, with a knowledgeable and/or well-funded adversary, you do not want to use RSA to directly encrypt data if you want that data to be kept secret.

I would recommend just using [gnupg](http://www.gnupg.org/) instead.  It's solved all those problems for you.

Comment: are you talking about common modulus attack?

Comment: @amwinter - If the value is too small and the exponent is also small (which is generally the case) then it's possible to trivially take the root of the result to get the original message.  That doesn't reveal anything about the private key, but it does render the encryption useless.  There is another attack that does reveal information about the private key, but I can't remember its name, so you might be right.  There is also a chosen plaintext attack on signing, which is why you always sign hashes.

Comment: @amwinter - I looked it up.  I'm actually talking about attacks related to low encryption exponents.  One way of solving the low encryption exponent problem is to send messages shorter than the maximum size and pad them with lots of random data, which is exactly what gnupg does when it encrypts the symmetric key used for doing the actual encryption.

Comment: @amwinter: Just use the standard PKCS#1 padding.

Comment: @GregS - The 'standard PKCS#1 padding` is really complicated.  Just use a tool that does it already.

Answer (score 3):

[PyCrypto](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/)

Comment: Did you want to contribute to it, or use it?

Comment: @gregs I want it to be secure and borrow C code from proven projects

Comment: @amwinter: no can tell you for sure it is secure, that you'll have to decide that for yourself. PyCrypto has a track record, so perhaps that will satisfy you.

Comment: Wow, this is a truely sad day for Stackoverflow. Two rather good crypto libraries have been out-voted by pycrypto, which is one of the worst library in existence. (I.e. pycrypto suffers from incompletness, lack of paddings and a horrible interface)

Comment: @Accipitridae No, this is a great day for Stackoverflow. The purpose of the site is to build all of our knowledge. You seem to know quite a bit about crypto. Please enlighten us about the advantages and disadvantages of each package (a separate answer is probably most appropriate).

Comment: @Barry Wark, a library that does not use any padding scheme for RSA in 2010 should already scare anyone away. For an attack against DSA if used as described by the authors see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729468/dsa-module-in-python/2751268#2751268. Stackoverflow can point to relevant material, but itself doesn't build the knowledge of the reader. There are too many answers that are just plain guesses.

Comment: you guys sound smart, I'm switching my answer to gpg

Comment: @Barry Wark, PyCrypto (as of v2.4.1) doesn't do PKCS#1 yet, so its RSA code shouldn't be used by anyone except other crypto library authors.

Comment: @amwinter I started taking US contributions last year.  You can find more info here: http://lists.dlitz.net/pipermail/pycrypto/2010q4/000286.html

Answer (score 2):

[pycryptopp](http://tahoe-lafs.org/trac/pycryptopp)

Answer (score 1):

```
def gcd (a, b):
    "Compute GCD of two numbers"

    if b == 0: return a
    else: return gcd(b, a % b)

def multiplicative_inverse(a, b):
    """ Find multiplicative inverse of a modulo b (a > b)
        using Extended Euclidean Algorithm """

    origA = a
    X = 0
    prevX = 1
    Y = 1
    prevY = 0

    while b != 0:

        temp = b
        quotient = a/b
        b = a % b
        a = temp

        temp = X
        a = prevX - quotient * X
        prevX = temp

        temp = Y
        Y = prevY - quotient * Y
        prevY = temp

    return origA + prevY

def generateRSAKeys(p, q):
    "Generate RSA Public and Private Keys from prime numbers p & q"

    n = p * q
    m = (p - 1) * (q - 1)

    # Generate a number e so that gcd(n, e) = 1, start with e = 3
    e = 3

    while 1:

        if gcd(m, e) == 1: break
        else: e = e + 2

    d = multiplicative_inverse(m, e)   

    # Return a tuple of public and private keys 
    return ((n,e), (n,d))           

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print "RSA Encryption algorithm...."
    p = long(raw_input("Enter the value of p (prime number):"))
    q = long(raw_input("Enter the value of q (prime number):"))

    print "Generating public and private keys...."
    (publickey, privatekey) = generateRSAKeys(p, q)

    print "Public Key (n, e) =", publickey
    print "Private Key (n, d) =", privatekey

    n, e = publickey
    n, d = privatekey

    input_num = long(raw_input("Enter a number to be encrypted:"))
    encrypted_num = (input_num ** e) % n
    print "Encrypted number using public key =", encrypted_num
    decrypted_num = encrypted_num ** d % n
    print "Decrypted (Original) number using private key =", decrypted_num
```